# Detect if string contains at least 2 letters (form any language) and at least 2 words

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, multibyte

I would like to make function which detects/validates that a string got at least 2 words, and each word has at least 2 letters (except for the two letters, it can contain any other char {without numbers}, but I don't care which and how many).

Now, I am not sure if I should use regex for this or I can do it in other ways.

If I need to make regex for it, I also dont know how to do it because I need to check all the letters available.

This is the regex I got now `[A-Za-z]{2,}(\s[A-Za-z]{2,})` which validates 2 words and 2 letters at least in each word.

**EDIT**:
After re-thinking I decided to support most languages since kr-jp-cn languages work differently than rest of languages. My main rules won't let kr-jp-cn letters count as letters but as chars.

**EDIT2:**

This is the function I'm using based on @message answer.

```
function validateName($name)
{
    if (strcspn($name, '0123456789') == strlen($name)) //return the part of the string that dont contain numbers and check if equal to it length - if it equal than there are no digits - 80% faster than regex.
    {
        $parts = array_filter(explode(' ',$name)); //should be faster than regex which replace multiple spaces by single one and then explodes.
        $partsCount = count($parts);
        if ($partsCount >= 2)
        {
            $counter = 0;
            foreach ($parts as $part)
            {
                preg_match_all('/\pL/u', $part, $matches);

                if (count($matches[0]) >= 2)
                {
                    $counter++;
                }
            }
        }

        if ($counter == $partsCount)
        {
            return 'matches';
        }
    }

    return 'doesnt match';
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: In *any* language? Well, I can imagine some languages (e.g.: Chinese) where there's no word/letter separation.

Comment: interesting... Since I dont know how Chinese works, I dont know what to do about it XD... Any idea whats the euqal in Chinese to 2 words 2 letters in each?

Comment: I assume he wants to match letters (as per definition) and not match non-alphabetic writing systems.

Comment: There isn't one. Chinese is formed from block characters which operate as sort of an intermediary between words and letters; there are no spaces in Chinese. Korean and (to a lesser extent) Japanese also contain similar structures. However, you can probably get away with a minimum character count in these cases.

Comment: Ok, after re-thinking I decided to drop support for those languages - everyone can write his name in English, some might use latin words and some might use Spanish words but in general my main rules are enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would use regex also

```
preg_match('/\w{2,}\s+\w{2,}/u', 'word слово');
```

`\w{2,}` matching word character 2 or more.
`\s+` matching all spaces between
and using `/u` [unicode modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Edit:

I thought that such solution will help, but you need something more complex like

```
$text = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', 'word w.s');

$parts = explode(' ', $text, 2);
if (count($parts) < 2) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Should have more than two words');
}

foreach ($parts as $part) {

    preg_match_all('/\w/u', $part, $matches);

    if (count($matches[0]) < 2) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('Should have more than two letters in word');
    }
}
```

Comment: Some explanation about your syntax would be interesting.

Comment: @Jocelyn what exactly needs to be explained?

Comment: 'word w.s' doesnt match although it contains 2 words and 2 letters in each.

Comment: @Ron, try to use [^\s]{2,}\s+[^\s]{2,} Matches everything except space

Comment: @message this one will match 'word w.' < only one letter in the second word.... which isnt good, need atleast 2 letters [thier position can be anywhere in the word and they dont have to follow each other..]

Comment: change this preg_replace('/\s+/', '', 'word w.s'); into this (look in the replacement pos) preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', 'word w.s');

Answer (score 2):

Use [Unicode character properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property).

`\p{L}` or `\p{Letter}` matches a code point with the Letter property in any language. [php.net documentation on Unicode character properties](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use these words from the strings afterwards regex is not the way to go. Regex is not a parser. The best way I can see doing this is a combination of [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [ctype_alpha()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php). 
Something along the lines of

```
$prepstring = $string;

//Remove all spaces from the original string and check that everything is a char
if(ctype_alpha(str_replace(array(' '), '', $prepstring))){

  //If everything is a char explode your string into an array
  explode($string);

  if(isset($string[1])){
    //Everything checks out, do something here.
  }

}
```

Comment: Does your code work with cyrillic characters? The OP asked "from any language".